# Centering minipage content within a Tikz graph node

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, graphs, tikz-node

Thanks to an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600445/removing-an-unneeded-arrow-head-from-graph?noredirect=1#comment1505933_600445), I have the following code for a Tikz graph with lists in each node:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \definecolor{BulletsColor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.9}
    \newlist{myBullets}{itemize}{1}
    
    \setlist[myBullets]{
      label=\textcolor{BulletsColor}{\textbullet},
      leftmargin=*,
      topsep=0ex,
      partopsep=0ex,
      parsep=0ex,
      itemsep=0ex,
      before={\color{BulletsColor}}
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
      \node[draw, rounded corners] (dataTypes)  {
        \begin{minipage}{4.5cm} Data types
          \begin{myBullets}
            \item a
            \item b
          \end{myBullets}
        \end{minipage}
      };
    
      \node[draw, rounded corners] (signalTypes) [above=of dataTypes] {
        \begin{minipage}{4.5cm} Signal types
            \begin{myBullets}
              \item x
              \item y
            \end{myBullets}
        \end{minipage}
        };
    
    \draw[->, thick] (signalTypes.south) --(dataTypes);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to center the list content and title of each node but unfortunately I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering the title of each node is easy enough. However, you cannot (really) center an `itemize` or `enumerate` enviroment. These create lists and they are not meant to be centered. There is an answer to a similar question on stackoverflow you may want to consult for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59551912/14169367

What you can achieve is this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       [node distance=.5cm,
       typelist/.style={anchor=north, text width=3.5cm, yshift=.5cm, blue, font=\small}
       ]
        \node[] (st) at (0,0) {Signal types};
        \node[below= of st,typelist,align=center] (stlist) {
            $\circ$ x\\
            $\circ$ y
        };
        
        \node[below= of stlist,yshift=-1cm] (dt) {Data types};
        \node[below= of dt,typelist,align=center] (dtlist) {
            $\circ$ x\\
            $\circ$ y
        };
        
        \node[fit=(st) (stlist),rounded corners,draw,thick](stbox) {};
        \node[fit=(dt) (dtlist),rounded corners,draw,thick](dtbox) {};
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth] (stbox) -- (dtbox);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**: To make sure longer text gets aligned properly, you could make a `node` for each element. BTW: This is not a very elegant solution, but I guess it works well enough to be a starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [node distance=.5cm,
        typelist/.style={anchor=north, text width=3.5cm, blue, font=\small}
        ]
        \node[] (st) at (0,0) {Signal types};
        \begin{scope}[node distance=0cm]
            \node[below= of st,typelist,align=center] (stlist1) {$\circ$ x};
            \node[below= of stlist1,typelist,align=center] (stlist2) {$\circ$ Some very long text too check the alignment};
        \end{scope}
        \node[fit=(st) (stlist2),rounded corners,draw,thick](stbox) {};
        
        \node[below= of stbox,yshift=-1cm] (dt) {Data types};
        \begin{scope}[node distance=0cm]
            \node[below= of dt,typelist,align=center] (dtlist1) {$\bullet$ x};
            \node[below= of dtlist1,typelist,align=center] (dtlist2) {$\bullet$ Some very long text too check the alignment};
        \end{scope}
        \node[fit=(dt) (dtlist2),rounded corners,draw,thick](dtbox) {};
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth] (stbox) -- (dtbox);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code results in this:

[image]

**EDIT2:** If you want the items to be aligned on the left, then I guess you're back to square 1 using `itemize`. I added a `draw` command to the top box to visualise that this environment is actually centered, even though it does not look like this at first glance. You can improve this behaviour slightly using a `varwidth` environment.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [node distance=.5cm,
        typelist/.style={anchor=north, text width=3.5cm, blue, font=\small,yshift=.5cm}
        ]
        \node[] (st) at (0,0) {Signal types};
            \node[below= of st,typelist,align=center,draw] (stlist) {
                \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
                    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                        \item x
                        \item Some very long text to check the alignment
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{varwidth}
            };
        \node[fit=(st) (stlist),rounded corners,draw,thick](stbox) {};
        
        \node[below= of stbox,yshift=-.5cm] (dt) {Data types};
            \node[below= of dt,typelist,align=center] (dtlist) {
                \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
                    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
                        \item x
                        \item Some very long text to check the alignment
                    \end{itemize}
                \end{varwidth}
            };
        \node[fit=(dt) (dtlist),rounded corners,draw,thick](dtbox) {};
        \draw[thick,->,>=stealth] (stbox) -- (dtbox);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very good starting point. Thank you very much. However, whenever I have a mix of very long and short strings in my list, the alignment isn't correct anymore. For example,
"$\circ$ xfgdgdfdfg\\
$\circ$ dgdfgdfgdf \\
$\circ$ dgdf". Is there a way to align strings with different lengths correctly?

Comment: I added an alternative to account for this. Although I am the first to admit that this code contains a lot of manual shifting around and there is quite likely a more elegant way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much but that's not (yet) quite what I would like to achieve. It would be great to align the circles, such that they are all at the same horizontal position. Would it be better to open a new question for this?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your second edit is exactly what I was looking for.